# Need help adjusting ASP.NET that uses Azure AD to also allow SSO from third party

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

We have a ASP.NET application that uses Microsoft's common login to log in the users, then it redirects back to our web application (in Azure). The authentication is connected to Azure Active Directories. It is a multi-tenant application with multiple Azure ADs. When Microsoft redirects back to our site, we use the information to create a cookie that is used for the web calls. In addition, the call back returns a user code that we use to get a token. This is used as authentication against our API controllers.

This has been working for a long time. Now, however, we need to integrate with another 3rd party portal that will launch our product. They will be using SAML for SSO. They are not integrated with Azure AD. So, the idea is that we validate the users via the SAML assertions. That will contain the username that we then want to "log in" with.

I can create the cookie off of this information and that works fine with our web controller calls. However, since I'm not getting a callback from Azure AD, I don't have the token for the API calls. I have tried to call Azure AD to authenticate the applications, but that does seem to satisfy the API Controller's authorization. Specifically, RequestContext.Principal.Identity doesn't seem to be set with this pattern.

I have set the cookie authentication with this code:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/home/login"),
    AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    CookieHttpOnly = true,
    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
    CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
};

// Forms/Cookie Authentication
app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
```

And I left the bearer token authentication code like this:

```
// Bearer Token Authentication used for API access
BearerAuthenticationOptions = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Tenant = <application tenant id>,
    AuthenticationType = OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    // Disable Issuer validation. We'll validate the Isuuer in the ClaimsAuthorizationFilter.
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = <resource id>,
        ValidateIssuer = false
    },

};

app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(BearerAuthenticationOptions);
```

The code that handles the Azure AD auth (that the SAML login should replace) is:

```
var openIdConnectOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {     ClientId = <ClientId>,  Authority = "https://login.windows.net/common/",    // setting this to false uses the cookie expiration instead     UseTokenLifetime = false,   TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters   {       // we'll validate Issuer on the SecurityTokenValidated notification below       ValidateIssuer = false  },

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications    {       // An AAD auth token is validated and we have a Claims Identity         SecurityTokenValidated = context =>         {           ... additional validation is performed here...

            return Task.FromResult(0);      },

        //the user has just signed in to the external auth provider (AAD) and then were redirected here         // with an access code that we can use to turn around and acquire an auth token         AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>      {           var code = context.Code;            var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

            var appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;          // causes the retreived API token to be cached for later use            TokenService.GetUserLevelTokenFromAccessCode(new HttpUserSessionWithClaimsId(identity), code, <ApiResourceId>, new Uri(appBaseUrl));

            return Task.FromResult(0);      },      // We are about to redirect to the identity provider (AAD)      RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>         {           // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request            // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.          var appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;          context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";             context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;

            context.HandleResponse();

            return Task.FromResult(0);      },      // Something went wrong during this auth process        AuthenticationFailed = context =>       {           if (context.Exception is Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
                .OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException)            {
                //This is a message we can't do anything about, so we want to ignore it.
                Log.Info("AuthenticationFailed in OpenIdConnectAuthentication middleware", context.Exception);          }           else            {
                Log.Error("AuthenticationFailed in OpenIdConnectAuthentication middleware",
                    context.Exception);             }

            // IDX10205 == Tenant validation failed             var message = (context.Exception.Message.StartsWith("IDX10205"))
                ? InvalidTenantMessage
                : GenericErrorMessage;

            context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/?Error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(message));          context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception             return Task.FromResult(0);      },      MessageReceived = context =>        {           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.ProtocolMessage.Error))          {
                // AADSTS65004 == user did not grant access in OAuth flow
                Log.Error("MessageReceived containing error in OpenIdConnectAuthentication middleware. \nError: {0}\nDescription: {1}"
                        .FormatWith(context.ProtocolMessage.Error, context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription));
                //context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/");
                //context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception           }           return Task.FromResult(0);      }   } };

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConnectOptions);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the value I put for AuthenticationType in the cookie was causing the disconnect. Once I fixed that, the data came through. So closing his question.
Thanks.